# Proper choice of rules in VS2010's static analyzer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-analysis

There are many groups in VS2010's static analyzer:

- All Rules
- Basic Correctness Rules
- Basic Design Guideline Rules
- Extended Correctness Rules
- Extended Design Guideline Rules
- Globalization Rules
- Minimum Recommended Rules
- Security Rules

But it is too hard to decide on a proper option.
What option do you use? What option do most of people use?

I usually work with C/C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I like the following:

- Basic Correctness Rules
- Basic Design Guideline Rules
- Extended Correctness Rules
- Extended Design Guideline Rules
- Security Rules

But then I'm slightly obsessed with code and design clarity. There are some places where the Design rules become a nuisance rather than a help because some of them are just recommendations and there are times when I'm going against the rules to achieve a hack or something. But if you manage a team that doesn't have a good understanding of design these rules can help you out a bit.